# Getting Cannot convert from Set<MyObject> to Set<MyObject<?,?>>

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Here is my code:

```
Set<MyObject<?, ?>> mySet = getSetOf(MyObject.class);

public <T> Set<T> getSetOf(Class<T> setClass) {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    // ...
    return set;
}
```

So basically I want to write a method that returns a set of objects of specific class type. The compiler is complaining the return type of `getSetOf(Class)` is not the same as the declaration of `mySet`. If I change the declaration of `mySet` to `Set<MyObject> mySet` then it is happy. But I am following the practice to not using raw type to declare variable, hence parameterised it.

How do you resolve this?

Comment: `Set<MyObject>` is *not* raw type... Show us how does `MyObject` class look like.

Comment: @alfasin said `Set<MyObject>` is _not_ raw type... : sorry `MyObject` is a generic class that takes two parameters (not shown above).

Comment: Such a method is completely pointless.

Comment: @alfasin said Show us how does `MyObject` class look like : sorry it does not matter and is not the point in this question. You can replace `MyObject<?, ?>` with `List<?>` and my question still valid.

Comment: If you'll be able to provide a minimal concrete example that shows what you're talking about, I'd gladly dig into it further. Right now it's now clear to me what you're doing/trying to do, either with your object nor with `getSetOf()`.

Comment: @Michael said Such a method is completely pointless : can't believe you said such a thing when you do not know what the method does...

Comment: Not saying he's right, but it's part of your responsibility when you post a question to explain *what* you're trying to do (not *how* you're trying to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Class<T>` parameter is there purely for the type information of `T`, then it's unnecessary. You can return a generic `Set<T>`, and it will figure out what `T` is based on type inference.

```
Set<MyObject<?,?>> mySet = getSet();

public <T> Set<T> getSet() {
    Set<T> set = new HashSet<>();
    // ...
    return set;
}

class MyObject<T,U> {}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/67vBU1)

If you actually do need the `Class<T>` for the purposes of reflection, change it to `Class<?>` so that it doesn't affect the inferred type of `T`.

Comment: Though it's true I don't see any added value in doing something like that: in order to add objects of type `MyObject` into the set you'll have to cast them to `T`...

Comment: @4castle wait, there is an issue that when I use `getSetOf(MyObject.class).forEach(o -> o.someMethod())` it does not recognise `o` is of type `MyObject`?

Comment: @user1589188 The type inference will only work if you provide the type of `T` in some way. Assigning to a variable is one way to do that.

Comment: @user1589188 I feel like I could help you way more if I knew why you need the `Class<?>` parameter. Are you using it to create instances of `MyObject`? If so, you would be better off passing a method reference to the constructor as the parameter using `Supplier<T>`.

Comment: @4castle Thanks. Like you said, I am using reflection to collect a set of any particular class objects within the member fields of a class object instance.